# salt-cloud: use map.sls from GitFS

Tags: salt-stack, salt-cloud

Is there a way of invoking salt-cloud with a map file from GitFS?

i.e. can I run something like this: `sudo salt-cloud -m salt://map.sls`?

Edit: Seems like this currently is not possible. As per @Utah_Dave's suggestion I created an [issue in github](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/26916).

Answer (score 1):

That's not supported right now.

Salt Cloud requires the map file exist on the same box Salt Cloud is running from.

I think that's an interesting use case, though. I can see how that would be handy to keep the map files in git. I think it should be doable to add that feature in. Please feel free to open an issue requesting that feature here: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/new

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @Utah_Dave. Ideally I would like to manage all of my salt config files all though git (with the exception of pillars and files that contain keys, such as cloud.providers). Is there any documentation on which files can be managed with git and what the best practices are around structuring them?

Comment: Right now Salt can only manage the contents of its file_roots and pillar data using git. Salt's config files are kept in `/etc/salt` and can be managed how you would manage any other config files.